# Can anyone get ruby-tk working on Mountain Lion?

Tags: ruby, xcode4, macports, tk-toolkit, osx-mountain-lion

```
sudo port install ruby19 +mactk
```

runs happily without errors on Mountain Lion with Xcode 4.4 freshly installed with command line tools and the macports package for Mountain Lion installed, but a previously working ruby-tk script throws this error:

```
./foot.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- tk (LoadError)
```

Any ideas?  Many TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I am an idiot.  Forgot to replace the native ruby, a la

```
$ sudo mv /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby.ORIG
$ sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/ruby1.9 /usr/bin/ruby
```